# Why are gameobjects not visible in the Scene Tab but visible in the Game Tab?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am working on a Unity project. I save it, and then I open more later, and now it's not showing the objects in the Scene tab.
However, in the Game tab, it does.
I read these forums, and the majority think it's because objects are not in the same layer option or something with the camera.

Links [here](https://forum.unity.com/threads/game-objects-visible-in-game-tab-but-not-on-scene-tab.106400/) , [here](https://forum.unity.com/threads/cant-see-gameobjects-in-game-but-they-are-visible-at-scene-tab.1023247/) and [this](https://forum.unity.com/threads/problem-with-invisible-gameobjects.254532/).

Here are a Gameobject that dont showing in Scene Tab. It's a rectangle:
[image: Mesh renderer are enable]
My main camera is working well, showing all the objects correctly:
[image: My main camera is working well, showing all the objects correctly.]
All gameobjects are set up in the "Everything" option:
[image: All gameobjects are set up in the "Everything" option.]

Comment: Because you’re not facing where your tiles are. As the pantomime goes. "Its behind you"

Comment: I've shifted the axes X, Y, and Z and have not shown any objects.

Comment: Focus on the camera and point in its direction.

Comment: Also whats that second blue thing looks like an eye crossed out

Comment: I think you are just too far away in scene, select any object and hit "F" in scene view

Comment: Thank you @DigvijaysinhGohil and everyone. It was solved.  Thank you for your comments. I am laughing at myself; this question was so dumb. Thank you for your patience and for not making fun of me.